# How to stop Word from Auto-Capitalizing?

Tags: microsoft-word, autocorrect

After an enter or a full stop, MS-Word will auto-capitalize the next word. This is really annoying when you're writing technical documentation with lots of code, field names etc. How do I turn it off?

I'm using Word 2003, but answers for any version of word will probably be useful for other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's under your AutoCorrect settings for Word 2003

[**Selecting/Deselecting AutoCorrect Options**](http://www.uwec.edu/HELP/Word03/AUTO-correplace.htm)

- From the Tools menu, select AutoCorrect Options...

  The AutoCorrect dialog box appears.
- Select the AutoCorrect tab

  The AutoCorrect options are preceded by checkboxes.
- Click the checkboxes for the options you want to activate

  [image]

  NOTE: A checkmark in the box indicates an option is selected and active.
- Click OK

Here's [how to do it in Word 2007](http://www.technipages.com/word-2007-enabledisable-auto-capitalization.html)

Comment: Note that the screenshot doesn't have circles on the correct option, though, since it's most likely the "Capitalize first letter of sentences", that he wants to uncheck.

Comment: This any better?

Comment: Thanks, I was looking in the Options dialog instead of the Autocorrect options ...